# How to change regression model in seaborn pairplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I can create regression plot with seaborns `regplot`, where I can change the order of the linear regression model with the `order` option, or choose a lowess model with the `lowess=True` option as in:

```
sns.regplot(x='logAssets', y='logLTIFR', lowess=True, data=df, scatter_kws={'alpha':0.15}, line_kws={'color': 'red'})
```

and obtain this:

[image]

Is it possible to change the order of the linear regression in a `pairplot`?

Or even better, to use a lowess model in seaborn `pairplot`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For more advanced usage, use `PairGrid` instead of `pairplot`. Basically, `PairGrid` allows you to control which function is used to plot the upper, lower and diagonal plots independently.
 [Check out the documentation for PairGrid for more details.](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.PairGrid.html#seaborn.PairGrid)

To answer your specific question:

```
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
g = sns.PairGrid(iris)
g = g.map_upper(sns.regplot, lowess=True, scatter_kws={'alpha':0.15}, line_kws={'color': 'red'})
```

[image]